# $($args[2]) is not printing argument passed

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file (runPowerShell.bat) with the following line:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5
```

> %1 is psFile in which the powershell file is passed in
>
> %2 is another argument i intend to pass later
>
> %3 is the arg i wanna print for now

The powershell file (scriptWrapper.ps1) contains this:

```
param($App_input)

$Script = "$($args[2])" #%2 for process or sync

write-host $Script
```

There is another PowerShell file called

> Process.ps1

that i wish to pass as %3 argument, meaning `$args[2]`

if i say `write-host "$args[2]"` it prints like this:

Process.ps1[2]

so it kinda works but i dont want the positional parameter with it, so I followed this thread for guidance, and the solution (`$($args[2])`) makes sense, but I am unsure why its not working for me

[accessing the $args array in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326205/accessing-the-args-array-in-powershell)

it prints nothing:

[image: Not printing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why...

so apparently, args does not bode well with param().

I had `param($App_input)` that takes %1 for an app input first before the Process.ps1 input for %2. and since param() has to be defined at the top of the script, it seems to have an unfriendly effect with args.

WHen i commented out param(), $($args[1]) printed out fine

however, instead of args, i should have just easily added $Script in param

```
param($App_input, $Script)
```

much better now