# Is there a dynamic variable for passed arguments in powershell?

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing

In batch, passed arguments can be used with %1, and onward counting. 
Lets say I have the following "batch.bat" script:

```
@ echo off
echo %1
pause>nul
```

If i call this from cmd like: `call batch.bat hello` it would output "*hello*" in the console.

Is there any variable in ps which does the same thing?

**EDIT**

I've found the folliwing, but it seems kind of unnatural.

```
$CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
Exit
}
```

Is there something more elegant perhaps?

Comment: $Args array you want example $Args[0]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this already but now i looked up $args and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12326218/11508928)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell has an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) `$args` that stores all arguments passed to a script (unless parameters were defined for the script). The individual arguments can be accessed by index (`$args[0]` for the first argument, `$args[1]` for the second, etc.).

However, in general it's advisable to [define parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) to control what arguments a script should accept, e.g.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$First,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [integer]$Second = 42
)
```

There are numerous advantages to this, including (but not limited to):

- arguments are parsed automatically and the values are stored in the respective variables
- scripts automatically prompt for mandatory parameters
- scripts throw an error if incorrect arguments are passed
- you can define default values for optional parameters
- you can have your script or function accept pipeline input
- you can [validate parameter values](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation/)
- you can use [comment-based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help) for documenting the parameters and their usage

Comment: Some additional info: in _simple_ functions / scripts (those without `[CmdletBinding()]` and/or `[Parameter()]` attributes) `$args` is still defined and contains positional arguments _not_ bound to declared parameters, if any; _advanced_ functions / scripts fundamentally only permit passing arguments that bind to declared parameters.

Comment: Another tip: To pass all positional arguments received through to another command, use `@args`.