# Call Windows executable from PowerShell script, passing all arguments

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I've looked all over, and I can't find the answer. Most things I've seen have answers that go around in circles and talk about all sorts of complicated things with no direct answer.

My question is simple. I have the following Windows batch file `foo.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
bar.exe %*
```

If I call `foo.bat foobar 123` from the command line, it invokes `bar.exe foobar 123`. This works with no command-line arguments. This works with multiple command-line arguments.

What is the equivalent PowerShell script that does basically the same thing: invoke another executable, passing all CLI parameters the user provided?

I wouldn't expect this would be difficult, but I sure can't find any straightforward answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PowerShell equivalent of your `foo.bat` file is a `foo.ps1` file with the following content:

```
# Passes all arguments received by this script to bar.exe
bar.exe @args
```

PowerShell exposes all (unbound) positional arguments<sup>[1]</sup>  as an array stored in the [automatic **`$args`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args).

By prefixing `$args` with `@` instead of `$`, argument [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) is employed, which means that the elements of the `$args` array are passed as *individual arguments* to `bar.exe`

- Note: This isn't strictly necessary when calling *external programs* (such as `bar.exe`) - `$args` would work there too - but is more versatile in that it can also pass *named* arguments correctly through to other *PowerShell* commands, which typically have *declared* parameters that can be bound by name (e.g., `-Path C:\temp` to bind value `C:\temp` to declared parameter `-Path`)

As for working with `$args` in general:

- `$args.Count` tells you how many (unbound) positional arguments were passed,
- `$args[0]` returns the first such argument, `$args[1]` the second, and so on.

However, it is usually preferable to formally *declare* parameters in PowerShell scripts and functions, which can then also be bound by *name* (e.g., `-FooParam foo` instead of just `foo`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880515/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] If your script doesn't *formally declare* any parameters (via a `param(...)` block - see [about_Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scripts#parameters-in-scripts) and the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880515/45375)), *all* arguments are by definition *unbound* (i.e. not mapped to a *declared* parameter) and *positional* (not prefixed by a target parameter *name*). However, if your script *does* declare parameters, `$args` only contains those arguments, if any, that were passed *in addition* to those binding to declared parameters. If your script is an [*advanced* script (or function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), `$args` isn't supported at all, because passing unbound arguments is then categorically prevented. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71429321/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: FYI... for a read: [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki]
(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)